# JQuery Class Toggle

Tags: jquery, class, toggle

We have a simple script to filter results:

```
$('ul.filter li a').click(function() {
    $('ul.filter li a').removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    var getvalue = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('.portfolioThumbs li.all').animate({opacity:0.1}).css('pointer-events', 'none');
    $('.portfolioThumbs li.'+getvalue).animate({opacity:1}).css('pointer-events', 'auto');
    return false;
});
```

Basically each ul.filter a link is a different filter button.

What we want is for the clicked filter button to stay highlighted (with class of selected) so they know what they are looking at, and then obviously if they click another filter button for this other filter to not stay highlighted, but instead highlight the new filter.

We tried the above which kind of works, but is there a better way?

Comment: What do you mean 'kind of works'? Formulate a specific question.

Comment: Ask this in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did right, another way to do that could be

```
$(this).addClass("selected").parent().siblings().children('a').removeClass('selected');
```